# term_sendkeys({buf},{keys}) move cursor to the next line if {keys} is empty

Tags: terminal, terminal-buffer

I am running `gvim 9.0` on `Windows 10`.
I am developing `Python` code.
I am using `Miniconda` and I run gvim from a `Miniconda CMD` shell.

For this reason I prepared a `.bat` file for starting `gvim` with the following content

```
@echo off
call C:\Users\myself\Miniconda3\condabin\activate.bat C:\Users\myself\Miniconda3\envs\myenv
gvim -c "vert botright call term_start('C:\\Users\\myself\\Miniconda3\\condabin\\conda.bat activate myenv && echo Conda env:%CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV% && ipython --profile=autoreload_profile', {'term_name': 'IPYTHON'})"
```

In my `.vimrc` I have defined the following variable and mapping

```
let g:ipython_terminal_name = 'IPYTHON'
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <F9> yy \| :call term_sendkeys(g:ipython_terminal_name,@")<cr>j0
```

but I noticed a strange behavior that I wish to explain through an example.
Consider the following text (on the left I reported the line numbers)

```
1 a = 3
2 b = 5
3 
4 c = 3
5 d = 4
6 
7 e = 5
```

If cursor is located on `line 3` and I hit `F9`, then nothing is sent to the terminal (as it should be) but then the cursor jumps directly to `line 5` (i.e. `line 4` is skipped).
This happens only when the cursor is located on a blank line.

I cannot understand why this happens, if someone could explain I would be grateful.
I would be even more grateful if someone could suggest a workaround.

If more details are needed, please let me know so I can update the question.

Comment: Without knowing where `g:ipython_terminal_name` comes from, it will be hard to reproduce this. Can you provide a minimal series of commands to establish the behavior (which, I agree, looks odd).

Comment: You are right! I have updated my question, I think the current informative level is enough to let people to reproduce, mutatis mutandis, the issue.